# The type src:Videogames was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, listbox, datatemplate

I'm trying to bind a collection of  `Videogame` objects to my ListBox and I'm getting this error despite following the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) example.

[image]

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        //Error is fired here.
        <src:Videogames x:Key="videogames" />
```

Here is my Videogame class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace UpcomingGames
{
    public class Videogame
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public string Synopsis { get; set; }
        public string Developer { get; set; }
    }

    public class Videogames : ObservableCollection<Videogame>
    {
        public Videogames()
        {
            Add(new Videogame {                   
                Name = "Fire Emblem", 
                ReleaseDate = "20/4/2011",
                Developer = "Rockstar Games", 
                Synopsis = @"Lorem ipsum dolor...",
            });
            Add(new Videogame { 
                Name = "Fire Emblem", 
                ReleaseDate = "20/4/2011",
                Developer = "Rockstar Games", 
                Synopsis = @"Lorem ipsum dolor...", 
            });
            Add(new Videogame{
                Name = "Fire Emblem",
                ReleaseDate = "20/4/2011",
                Developer = "Rockstar Games",
                Synopsis = @"Lorem ipsum dolor...",
            });
        }
    }
}
```

What might I be doing wrong and what can I do to solve this?

I haven't manually added any namespaces because the MSDN article didn't show me that. Is this something I need to do? Anyways, here's the current state of the XAML.

```
<Window x:Class="UpcomingGames.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="286" Width="199">
```

Comment: Can you paste code of your xaml where you have added the namespace srv?

Comment: @RV1987: I'm also getting this error, which I suspect is causing the other main error. `Error 2 ''src' is an undeclared prefix. Line 7, position 14.' XML is not valid.`

Comment: As Dave has already mentioned, you need to add the reference..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do for you -

```
<Window x:Class="UpcomingGames.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:src="clr-namespace:UpcomingGames"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="286" Width="199">
```

And for the error you report in the above post, just remove the assembly attribute from your namespace declaration.

Comment: OK, this worked fine. I only had to remove the `assembly` bit and it worked. Any reason why?

Comment: I am not sure of the problem but since you are not referencing to outer assembly, you are writing within a same assembly.So, whats the need of specifying the assembly name.

Comment: Even when you try adding the namespace, intellisense in xaml add an assembly only if you try accessing the namespace from outer assemblies.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a reference like this in your XAML

`xmlns:src="clr-namespace:UpcomingGames;assembly=UpcomingGames"`

This reference will go at the top of the XAML file and will be with others like this:

```
<Window x:Class="UpcomingGames.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:src="clr-namespace:UpcomingGames;assembly=UpcomingGames"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="286" Width="199">
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, now I'm getting this error: `The tag 'Videogames' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:UpcomingGames;assembly=UpcomingGames'. Line 8 Position 14.` Which is confusing because both of my classes are in the same `UpcomingGames` namespace.